# I am unable to get my code to get the stride of 7 to work properly C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

The question I am trying to solve is the following:

Write a function that traverses (and prints) the element of an array with stride =7. To do this the update part in the loop will be  i= (i+7) % n, where n is the array size.
Would this function visit all elements of the array? Try different array sizes to check when it is impossible to traverse all elements.

The code that I wrote below doesn't print the correct values in the arry even if the value of i is correct.

Can anyone help, I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int* CreateArray(int n);
void StrideArray(int arr[], int n);

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[3];

    arr = CreateArray(3);

    cout << "The Elements In The Array Are: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    StrideArray(arr, 3);

    cout << "The Elements In The Array Stride 7 Are: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}

int* CreateArray(int n)
{
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (rand() % 100);
    }

    return arr;
}

void StrideArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        i = (i + 7) % n;
        arr[j] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to rearrange the order of an array, you should make a copy.  Otherwise you'll be grabbing array elements that have already changed.

Comment: The problem statement asks you to print elements of the array, not to move them around (losing information in the process).

Comment: Hint : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in StrideArray you read back the modified values of arr.

```
void StrideArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int puffer=new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        i = (i + 7) % n;
        puffer[j] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        puffer[j] = arr[j];
    }
    debete[] puffer;
}
```

Is a good way to write the function.

Also it visits all element only if n isn't dividable by 7. So if n is not 7,14,21,...

Also to use cout you have to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: `delete[] puffer;`

Answer (score 0):

Your StrideArray function needs fixing; you are iterating over j but using i to index, which remains constant; and you are reassigning value at one index to another where as you are supposed to print it:

```
void StrideArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j=j+7)
    {
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

I modified the rest of your code for demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int* CreateArray(int n);
void StrideArray(int arr[], int n);

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[3];

    arr = CreateArray(21);

    cout << "The Elements In The Array Are: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    StrideArray(arr, 21);


    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}

int* CreateArray(int n)
{
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (rand() % 100);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Do not use ````using namespace std;````. Do never use raw pointers/new for owned memory. Do not use C-style arrays. Use ````std::vector```` instead. "arr" is allocated twice. This results in a memory leak. First new allocates memory, then function overwrites it immediately.  That's a clear bug. If you give an answer it should be correct or mention the problems. Everything else is misguiding . . .

Comment: Hi @ArminMontigny, thanks for your comment. I realized that there are many improvements points in the code but I focused only on suggesting solution to the subject problem. Is it not the best way?